# How to make timer component running while switching routes in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a timer(counter) component and use it in my `dashboard.html`. The program is about to see how much time left until the client arrives. 
How can I make my timer keep running when I am switching routes instead of resetting it to defautlt?

dashboard.html

```
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="bc">Welcome {{ appUser.username }}!</h1>
  <div class="row" *ngIf="appUser && appUser?.loggedIn && appUser?.isDoctor">
    <div class="col">
      <counter #counter></counter>
      <div><a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="add-new-client">Add new client</a></div>
      <div><a class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="my-clients" >My Clients</a></div>
      <div><a class="btn btn-info" routerLink="all-clients">All Clients</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" ><a class="btn btn-warning" (click)="LogOut()">Logout</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

dashboard.ts

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  appUser: User;
  clients: Client[] = [];
  today: Date = new Date(2019, 10, 26, 12, 20);     // Defualt todays time;

  @ViewChild('counter', {read: CounterComponent, static: false})
  private counter: CounterComponent;

  constructor(private userS: UserService,
              private clientService: ClientService,
              private router: Router) {
                setInterval(() => {
                  this.today.getTime(); //= new Date(2019, 10, 26, 12, 20);
                }, 1);
              }

  counterState = 'counter is ticking';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appUser = this.userS.currentUser;
    this.clients = this.clientService.getUserClients()
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return (new Date(a.registrationDate) as any) - (new Date(b.registrationDate) as any);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.counter.startAt = this.timeRemaining();
    this.counter.counterState.subscribe((msg)=>{
      if(msg === 'COMPLETE') {
        this.counterState = 'counter has stopped';
        alert('You need to serve a client!');
      }
    });
    this.counter.start();

  }

  private timeRemaining() {
    let t1 = this.clientService.getFirstInRowClient().registrationDate;
    let dif =  (t1.getTime() - this.today.getTime()) / 1000;
    if (dif < 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return dif;
  }
}
```

My routes in app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      [ { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
        { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthguardGuard], component: DashboardComponent},
        { path: 'dashboard/add-new-client', component: ClientFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]},
        { path: 'dashboard/all-clients', component: AllClientsComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]},
        { path: 'dashboard/my-clients', component: MyClientsComponent, canActivate: [AuthguardGuard]}
      ])
```

It should be ticking also when I am not in my `dashboard.html`

Edit: I created timer.service.ts but when I call `timeRemaining()` in dashboard it still resets everytime to defualt.

```
import { ClientService } from './client.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimerService {
  today: Date = new Date(2019, 10, 26, 12, 20);     // Defualt todays time;

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }


  timeRemaining() {
    let t1 = this.clientService.getFirstInRowClient().registrationDate;
    let dif =  (t1.getTime() - this.today.getTime()) / 1000;
    if (dif < 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return dif;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should creat your timer logic into a singleton, not into a component. The component would then display the timer from the service.

Comment: What do you mean? Should  I create a time service?

Comment: I mean that services (singletons exactly) are created once, and used throughout the app. Whereas, a component (and even more a routed one) is created when asked and removed when not needed. This means that everytime you destroy your component, your destroy the timer. But since you can't destroy the service (unless closing the browser tab of course), then your timer will live on, even if you have no components to display on your page.

Comment: How can I inject them correctly?

Comment: Like you would Inject any service in angular !

Comment: On ngInit() this.time = this.timeService.remainingTime()?